# IPv6 only bound services accessible from IPv4 on dual stack Linux host: how does it work?

Tags: ipv6

I have this situation where Apache is listening on :::443 only
on a Linux host that has both IPv6 and IPv4 enable.

I can access the content served by that Apache from IPV4 only enabled computer.

Can someone help me understand what's happening, and how to verify this configuration on a Linux host (CentOS in my case)

I read somewhere that

> [...] servers bind to IPv6 addresses (on all interfaces or on a specific one, if needed) and treat IPv4 as mapped ones because IPv6 and IPv4 share the same port space on the same machine. This works transparently thanks to glibc and is a recommended way to write networking applications. See man ipv6(7) for details.

I'd guess this means the only way this could happen would be with Ipv4 mapped address. However I can't get this working with `ping6 ::ffff:127.0.0.1` or to my public IPv4 address.
Besides I don't see any config that would support this when looking at `ip a`

Comment: You cannot use IPv4-mapped Addresses (`::ffff:0:0/96`) as source or destination addresses, they are not forwardable (routable), nor globally reachable, and they are reserved by the IPv6 protocol, itself; see _[IANA IPv6 Special-Purpose Address Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/iana-ipv6-special-registry/iana-ipv6-special-registry.xhtml)_. Basically, you can use those addresses to store IPv4 addresses in a common format with IPv6 addresses, e.g. a database.

Answer (score 4):

You can tell these are in use when `ss` output shows sockets with mapped addresses.

From [ipv6(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ipv6.7.html)

> IPv4 connections can be handled with the v6 API by using the
>   v4-mapped-on-v6 address type; thus a program needs to support only
>   this API type to support both protocols.  This is handled
>   transparently by the address handling functions in the C library.

Note "transparently". You don't give programs v4 mapped v6 addresses, you give them v4 addresses.

Socket option IPV6_V6ONLY defaults to v6 listening to v4 mapped v6, per the default of `/proc/sys/net/ipv6/bindv6only`.

This behavior is platform specific. Notably, it is a peculiarity of Linux.

Comment: Note that I find this incredibly good and convenient. It's just that I got used to read `netstat` to understand what was listening to what, usually making sure services were listening to both ipv4 and ipv6.
I just don't understand how this work. If a service is not listening on a port on ipv4, how the hell can the listener for ipv6 receives ipv4? 
This incidently also means that there no point for `sshd` for instance to listen to both stack as it usually does. I guess it's a matter of compatibility with older system.

Comment: I was not able to "see" anything about mapped address with `ss`. Just says `[::]:443` the same way `netstat` does.

Comment: Test by connecting to a service over both v4 and v6. If both are successful, you have the configuration correct. This functional test also will detect problems above layer 4.